# From a set of points in a plane (2D), discard isolated and group remaining

Tags: algorithm, geometry, graph-theory

I am currently working on a project that requires to solve the following problem:

Let's say that each time a user access a specific resource on the network from his mobile device, a system stores his position (latitude, longitude).

Then I need to be able to tell the user the "areas" from which he use to access that resource. And by "areas" y could mean circumferences (center & ratio).

The problem is I need some criteria to **discard isolated points** and I need some criteria for **grouping remaining points** into "areas".

I bet there must be some literature on the subject, but the issue is I dont even know the terms to refer this problem, and where to start looking.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested in clustering and/or outlier detection algorithms. The simplest option might be the [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) algorithm, which finds clusters in a dataset while ignoring points that are not sufficiently "connected" to other points.

Comment: Omg! That fix into my problem perfectly. I spent the past couple of days looking for it. I don't vote you up because I can't.
Thanks a lot!